# What are some good Windows email clients?

Tags: email-client, thunderbird

I have been using Thunderbird since its inception.  It has always been lagging in necessary features.  I am starting to get frustrated with it.  The final straw being that I can not collapse the account/folder tree.  I had a quick look at trying to write an extension for it.  But the learning curve is too high, and I don't even know if it will be possible.

I am looking for a client for Windows

1. Free or reasonably priced, preferably not a subscription.
2. Must support POP, not interested in IMAP.
3. Must work with MFA for Google accounts
4. Must support multiple email accounts with ease
5. Must work with Mailing Lists
6. Must import current emails from Thunderbird
7. Just want email, I don't care about Calendar or Tasks etc.

Any thoughts about **Mailbird**?

Answer (score 2):

1. [BlueMail](https://bluemail.me): free for personal use, proprietary and support for any protocol, offline-use, nice UI, multi-account support; excluding Thunderbird import (which is not listed in its feature page, but it should be mentioned in its docs) this should be perfect for you;
2. [Mailspring](https://getmailspring.com/): it is a freemium and open source cross-platform mail client. Premium version adds read receipts, send later, reminders and even more. Nice interface, easy to use and customizable (look at shortcut customization, this could be useful to you);
3. [Microsoft Outlook](https://www.outlook.com/): it is of course paid, closed source and I think it's perfect for business use (and seems not your case);
4. [MailBird](https://www.getmailbird.com/): it is a paid and proprietary mail client, Thunderbird's first competitor (de facto).

I think this is it. There are many other clients but I think these are the best for you accordingly to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I tried **Mailbird**.  Unfortunately the trial period is only 3 days.  I liked it's look and the new features as compared to **Thunderbird**, so I paid up.  But it has a few issues with mail filters.  The major one being that you can't move messages to another account (which is possible in Thunderbird).  And the filters are unreliable with very limited expressions.  I eventually received a refund (thanks).

Am about to try **Postbox** soon, although the support have a one track mind and will not read my question.  They are answering like a politician, who cares what you ask, just bang on about it's features.